# Mapforce - remove empty tag

Tags: xml, xslt, altova, map-force

I have a little problem with my MapForce-Transformation:
I want to print only the existing values in my result XML, but in my XML result file there is everytime a empty tag 
I check with a filter, if the result of my function is existing and if this is true, I will make the assignment. But, if the condition is false, the value  is printing too.

Example:

My Mapforcedocument:
[My assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFLHX.jpg)

My function:
[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqWIf.jpg)

My result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <BusinessPartners>
        <BusinessPartner>
            <ContactPerson>
                <LegalEntity>
                    <TeleCommunication/> - I don't want to print this
                </LegalEntity>
            </ContactPerson>
        </BusinessPartner>
    </BusinessPartners>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have unnecessary functions added after the output of your user function 'test'.  If the source XSD is setup correctly that function should work on its own.  Check the properties of customertype in the associated XSD and insure it's nillable(true) with a min occurs of 0.